# Trace of product of multiple operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

I'm self-studying QM from Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics, and was trying to solve Exercise 1.7.1 (ii) which asks the reader to show

$$ tr(\Omega \Lambda \Theta) = tr(\Lambda \Theta \Omega) = tr(\Theta \Omega \Lambda) $$
(and specifically mentions that the permutations are cyclic.)

$$\underline{\textbf{My Solution:}}$$
The trace of an operator $\Omega$ is given by $$Tr(\Omega) = \sum_{i} \Omega_{ii}$$ and $$\Omega_{ij} = \langle i| \Omega |j \rangle$$ so

$$
tr(\Omega \Lambda \Theta) = \sum_i (\Omega \Lambda \Theta)_{ii} = \sum_i \langle i | \Omega \Lambda \Theta | i \rangle  $$

Now, we can employ the useful property of the projection operator that $$\sum_i \mathbb{P}_i = \sum_i |i\rangle \langle i | = I$$

in order to write,
$$ (\Omega \Lambda \Theta)_{ii} = \langle i | \Omega \Lambda \Theta | i \rangle  \\
= \langle i | (\Omega \Lambda) I (\Theta) | i \rangle = \sum_j \langle i | (\Omega \Lambda) | j \rangle \langle j | (\Theta) | i \rangle $$ where $I$ is the Identity matrix

We can use the same method to rewrite $\langle i | (\Omega \Lambda) | j \rangle$ as
$$\langle i | (\Omega \Lambda) | j \rangle = \langle i | (\Omega) I (\Lambda) | j \rangle \\ = \sum_k \langle i | \Omega | k \rangle \langle k |\Lambda | j \rangle$$

So, combining the above results, we can write
$$Tr(\Omega \Lambda \Theta) = \sum_i (\Omega \Lambda \Theta)_{ii} = \sum_i\sum_j \sum_k \langle i| \Omega | k\rangle \langle k| \Lambda | j\rangle \langle j| \Theta| i\rangle $$

So,
$$ \boxed{Tr(\Omega \Lambda \Theta) = \sum_i\sum_j \sum_k \Omega_{ik} \Lambda_{kj} \Theta_{ji}} $$

Now, rearranging the summations in the above expression shouldn't change the result, but doing so gives us the expressions for $tr(\Lambda \Theta \Omega)$ and $tr(\Theta \Omega \Lambda)$ so we find
$$  tr(\Omega \Lambda \Theta) = tr(\Lambda \Theta \Omega) = tr(\Theta \Omega \Lambda)  $$

$$\underline{\textbf{Question about this solution:}}$$
I feel like there is something missing in my solution because it doesn't give any restrictions for the permutations of the operators. I don't see why this wouldn't also give the correct answer for, say, $Tr(\Omega \Theta \Lambda)$ which is not a cyclic permutation. Is there something lacking in my solution that would give such a restriction on the permutations?

Comment: Your derivation is correct. If you write out $\text{Tr}(\Omega\Theta\Lambda)$ you will see that it disagrees with the version of the expanded sum that you wrote as the 2nd last equation.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the response!